# read_json in pandas is out of order

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

I have json structure like this

```
{ 
    "namespace": "ndex", 
    "type": "record", 
    "name": "broker", 
    "fields": 
    [ 
        { 
            "default": null,
            "type": [ "null", "int" ],
            "name": "broker_id"
        }
```

when trying to read json using read_json pandas,the order is not as same as in json file.Key order is arranged alphabetically.

Is there any solution to read data without changing the order of keys.

PS: my code starts with read_json..so using json.loads or json.dump requires lots of code change.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4703 